# QRubberBand doesn't work

Tags: qt

I am using QRubberBand to draw a selection box on my QWidget that displays a QImage.

I am using the code exactly as it is shown in the documentation, but it doesn't work.  I get no errors, but it does act strange.  Instead of displaying a selection box when I hold my left button down and drag it across my QWidget which is painted with the QImage it just makes one of my buttons on my interface disappear and reappear based on my left button click.  I should also add that the button that disappears isn't apart of the QWidget, or even apart of the parent QObject that creates the QWidget.

```
void Widget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    origin = event->pos();
    if (!rubberBand)
        rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
    rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin, QSize()));
    rubberBand->show();
}

void Widget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin, event->pos()).normalized());
}

void Widget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    rubberBand->hide();
    // determine selection, for example using QRect::intersects()
    // and QRect::contains().
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you debug the application to make sure all events are being fired?

Comment: In your case, is it correct to use event->pos() or event->localPos()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is totally my fault.  I failed to set my pointer as NULL in my header.

Instead of this :

```
QRubberBand *rubberBand {rubberBand = NULL};
```

I just did :

```
QRubberBand *rubberBand;
```